# How can I put the <!CDATA> in a XML tag

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to put `<!CDATA>` in a specific tag in my `XML` file, but the result is `&lt;![CDATA[mystring]]&gt;`

Someone can help me ?

The encoding

```
XmlProcessingInstruction pi = doc.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml", "version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"");
```

How I'm doing

```
texto.InnerText = "<![CDATA[" + elemento.TextoComplementar.ToString() + "]]>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
XmlNode xnode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("entry/entry_status");

XmlCDataSection CData;
```

`InnerText` performs whatever escaping is required.

```
xnode.InnerText = "Hi, How are you..??";
```

If you want to work with `CDATA node` then:

```
CData = doc.CreateCDataSection("Hi, How are you..??");
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't explained how you are creating the XML - but it looks like it's via `XmlDocument`.

You can therefore use [`CreateCDataSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcdatasection.aspx).

You create the CData node first, supplying the text to go in it, and then add it as a child to an XmlElement.

You should probably consider [Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) for working with XML - in my most humble of opinions, it has a much more natural API for creating XML, doing away with the XML DOM model in favour of one which allows you to create whole document trees inline.  This, for example, is how you'd create an element with an attribute and a cdata section:

```
var node = new XElement("root", 
  new XAttribute("attribute", "value"),
  new XCData("5 is indeed > 4 & 3 < 4"));
```